# Spring Security only permit anonymous to access

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In Spring Security, I know a specific URL can be configured as only logged user or user with a specific role can access by the following statement:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
```

But is there a way to make it only accessible by the anonymous? which means it restricts the logged user to access. For example like login page, I want it to be not accessible if the user has logged in. Only make it accessible when there is no user logged in. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anonymous like this

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .requestMatchers()
    .antMatchers("/api/**")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/books/*").anonymous();
}
```